# How to (Java-)serialize Nashorn's JSObjects in Vert.x JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, serialization, vert.x, nashorn

In a **Vert.x JavaScript** verticle, I tried using the following code to serialize a JavaScript object:

```
var o={"foo":"bar"};
var baos=new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
var oos=new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(o);
```

However, the last line throws the following exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror
```

Looking at **Nashorn**'s API documentation it seems that `ScriptObjectMirror` and the implemented `JSObject` interface do not implement `Serializable` and hence the serialization fails.

**Is there a trick or workaround that would allow to serialize these objects?**

PS: I do not want to serialize them as JSON because the master function I plan to use should serialize all Java objects the same way.

---

Additional information:

1. I'm using Vert.x 3.5 with JVM 1.8.0_151 (OpenJDK) on Ubuntu 16.04
   64bit.
2. The JavaScript verticle is started with the command `vertx run main.js
   --conf=cfg.json --redeploy="*.js" --launcher-class=io.vertx.core.Launcher`.

Answer (score 0):

No, nashorn classes are not Serializable and that is a design decision. You've to use JSON to serialize nashorn script objects.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you tell the reason(s) for this design decision? Since I'm not a Java expert, I don't understand why this has been done...